# Audacity. При запись с микрофона линия "тишины" смещена относительно нуля

Tags: linux, alsa, pulseaudio

**Система:** Линукс Федора 64бит

При записи с микрофона довольно таки сильные шумы.
В Audacity видно, что средняя линия смещена вниз. Ну ладно, шумы можно списать на китайский микрофон (и подавить можно), но почему такие смещения относительно нуля?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что там (в ноле) есть напряжение. И АЦП фиксирует это напряжение (например там 0,1 вольт).

Comment: @nick_n_a, приблизительно я так и представлял. Но почему вдруг так? И можно что-то с этим сделать?

Comment: Можно вычислить среднее по амплитуде, за... допустим 1,2-5 секундный период при начале записи - это и будет "смещение ноля" - и затем вычесть смещение. (это програмно, я думал у вас разработка). Возможно где-то в настройках или микрофона или программы это есть.